# Render Silent and Abrupt Decay

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I cast [render silent](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=render%20silent) targeting [abrupt decay](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=abrupt%20decay), will my opponent still be unable to cast spells for the rest of the turn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your opponent will be unable to cast spells for the remainder of the turn.

The ruling on gather for Render Silent confirms this:

http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=369022

> A spell that “can’t be countered” is a legal target for Render Silent.
>   The spell won’t be countered when Render Silent resolves, but that
>   spell’s controller won’t be able to cast spells for the rest of the
>   turn.

Answer (score 2):

**No they can not cast spells for the rest of the turn.**

The second part of the spell is a seperate effect from the first.